# How to write a test to send json to a @RequestBody method by spring mvc test

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

My test

```
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
  byte[] bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(webFile);
  this.mockMvc.perform(post("/loadFile.json").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(bytes)).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

My Controller

```
@RequiredPermission(RequiredPermission.OperationType.viewProject)
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
ModelAndView load(@RequestBody WebFile document)
         { ... }
```

But always get 400 error

Answer (score 1):

In your test you are using URL `/loadFile.json` but in your controller you have `/loadFile`. Are you using some urlrewriter if not change the url in test class to `/loadFile`. All other codes in test class seems to be Ok.

Comment: I am using Jackson to convert object to json. Other tests running fine , so not be the url issue

Comment: Can you post your WebFile.java and json string (bytes).